# How to process recv return

Tags: c, string, sockets, recv

I´m getting a string like this from C socket `recv` function and would like ideas how to process it and get numeric values that comes beside the letters(S,L,E...) on the string

```
S@AB@L1550 @W
>E0578A9069C0000
>S0223W0418
>R2219H1429S0000
>G0156V0116T1800
>m0138
>m0087
```

For example letter, need to get the numeric 223 and the same to others;

Was thinking to do a loop and read all vector and checking the key words. 
But not sure if has some way easier or faster

Comment: Please explain your problem a bit further as it is not 100% clear.

Comment: @Idan I´m getting this string listed above from the recv function and need to get values from it. The values area the numbers that comes after a letter , for example E , need to get 57 , from W need to get 418. Was that clear ?

Comment: If it's a network stream, I would go with a char-by-char state-machine

Comment: If i understood correctly, your problem is not socket related. 
You need to understand how to take out the numbers from a char buffer. Is i correct?

Comment: @Idan, correct !! recv function results on a char* var type

Comment: How are numbers like 0578 (in the second line: E0578A…) interpreted?  Decimal with leading zero?  Octal could be an alternative, though it's unlikely.  Look up functions [`strcspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcspn.html)
[`strspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strspn.html)
[`strpbrk()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strpbrk.html); they'll help you isolate where the numbers are, and (used _carefully_), [`strtol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html) too.

Comment: I mean.. is there any chance that a letter/number sequence could be split over two recv() calls?  If so, there may be issues with 'straightforward' string library calls...

Comment: It would be a good idea if you showed what you've tried.  It's readily doable.  I'd use `strcspn()` and `strspn()` — they're ideal for this job.  The bookkeeping is fiddly rather than hard.  You should make sure that you null terminate the string received from `recv()` — the communications protocol won't necessarily transfer the null byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code demonstrates one way to do the job.

```
/* SO 4635-2633 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char data[] =
        "S@AB@L1550 @W\n"
        ">E0578A9069C0000\n"
        ">S0223W0418\n"
        ">R2219H1429S0000\n"
        ">G0156V0116T1800\n"
        ">m0138\n"
        ">m0087";
    const char digits[] = "0123456789";

    printf("Raw data:\n[%s]\n", data);

    size_t offset = 0;
    size_t skip;
    //for (skip = strcspn(data + offset, digits);
    //     data[skip] != '\0';
    //     skip = strcspn(data + offset, digits)) 
    while (data[(skip = strcspn(data + offset, digits))] != '\0')
    {
        size_t len = strspn(data + offset + skip, digits);
        if (len == 0)
            break;
        char numstr[32];
        memmove(numstr, data + offset + skip, len);
        numstr[len] = '\0';
        int number = atoi(numstr);
        printf("Number %4d (position %2zu..%-2zu - [%.*s])\n",
               number, offset + skip, offset + skip + len - 1,
               (int)len, data + offset + skip);
        offset += skip + len;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When run, the output is:

```
Raw data:
[S@AB@L1550 @W
>E0578A9069C0000
>S0223W0418
>R2219H1429S0000
>G0156V0116T1800
>m0138
>m0087]
Number 1550 (position  6..9  - [1550])
Number  578 (position 16..19 - [0578])
Number 9069 (position 21..24 - [9069])
Number    0 (position 26..29 - [0000])
Number  223 (position 33..36 - [0223])
Number  418 (position 38..41 - [0418])
Number 2219 (position 45..48 - [2219])
Number 1429 (position 50..53 - [1429])
Number    0 (position 55..58 - [0000])
Number  156 (position 62..65 - [0156])
Number  116 (position 67..70 - [0116])
Number 1800 (position 72..75 - [1800])
Number  138 (position 79..82 - [0138])
Number   87 (position 86..89 - [0087])
```

You can use the `for` loop in place of the `while` loop at the cost of duplicating the call to `strcspn()`.  I preferred not to repeat myself.

Comment: your logic works fine but is only listing the values on the string and what I´m trying to do is a way is get values from the string and save on variable. For example value after E(057), will be saved in a var1 then do the same with others like S,A,C.

Comment: And what is the problem with saving the values?  Apart from the fact that using names like `var1`, `var2`, … `var14` is painful and should be replaced by elements of an array: `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, … `arr[13]`?  If you need to get the letter before the number, that's doable too.

Comment: Not saying it´s a problem to save the values, only saying the logic should be based on letter instead numbers. As far I understood (and sorry if I´m wrong) you going trough the string searching for numeric values right? while I think the correct way should go trough the string searching for letters. Code would be like going trough the string and if found E, then "ops wait I found E so save subsequent value on varx or var[0]" and keep searching until end of string. Not saying ur code is wrong, just trying to make code myself with what I need.

Comment: Well, your sample data doesn’t show any case where the digits are not preceded by a letter, so there’s no obvious reason to spend time looking at the letters. You know more about the requirements than you illustrate in the question— that’s not unusual, but you have to illustrate what you’re after. We can’t guess what you’re dealing with. We only have the question to go on.   What, in your opinion, needs to change? And why can’t you make the change?

Answer (score 1):

I will explain the general idea and let you write the code by yourself.

1. Create a char buffer which contains the entire string.
2. Create another char buffer at the size of 5, the number of digits in each number - call it digits_char_array.
3. Run in a loop over the char buffer and if the current char is a letter, copy the follwoing 4 chars to digits_char_array. You can use strncpy or memcpy.
4. Convert digits_char_array by using an appropriate function, such as [atol](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atol.htm)